# Conectar a BD Informix desde C#

Tags: c#, informix

Estoy tratándome de conectar a una base de datos Informix desde una aplicación de C#, ocupando el siguiente código

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string _ConnectionString = "Server=1.1.1.1:7770;UID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;Authentication=1.1.1.1:7770; ";
            IfxConnection _Cnn = new IfxConnection(_ConnectionString);            

            try
            {
                _Cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Se ha realizado la conexion correctamente");
                _Cnn.Close();
                _Cnn.Dispose();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error al conectar a la base de datos: {0}", ex.Message));
            }            
        }
```

Pero me devuelve este error:

> ERROR [08001][IBM]SQL30081N Se ha detectado un error en las
>   comunicaciones. Protocolo de comunicaciones que se está utilizando:
>   "TCP/IP". API de comunicaciones que se está utilizando: "SOCKETS".
>   Ubicación donde se ha encontrado el error: "148.218.x.x". Función de
>   comunicación que ha detectado el error: "recv". Codigo(s) de error
>   especifico(s) del protocolo: "*","*","0", SQLSTATE=08001

¿Alguien sabe por qué estoy obteniendo este error?

Comment: Si usas algun manager para administrar la db, puedes conectarte con esa info que aplcias en el connection string ? esta claro que el error son los datos que proporcionas, debes estar seguro que esa es la ip y el puerto y que ningun firewall lo esta bloqueando

Comment: edito los datos de conexion, por favor si los mismos eran reales, comunicate con los moderadores de forma urgente para que eliminemos esa informacion de todos lados.

Comment: No cuento con ningún manager. el DBA me asegura que el probó la conexión y que esta es satisfactoria. Uso el Client SDK de Informix para conectarme y al parecer los datos proporcionados por el DBA son correctos (él mismo los confirma). He desactivado el firewall de Windows y no tengo instalado ningún antivirus, por eso se me hace muy raro